# can't use array operator to array-based pointers (read access violation)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, operators, memory-address

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to use pointers, avoiding `new` keyword to obtain the same copying behaviour like in some other languages (operator `=` assigns a ref of right operand to the left one if we talk about objects, similar to what `shared_ptr` is supposed to offer). What I'm gonna show seems to work if I DON'T use the array operator `[]`. Why does that happen and how can I get around it?

```
// Declaration way before
std::vector<int>* test;

test = &std::vector<int>();
(*test)[1] = 0;
```

```
// Declaration way before
std::map<std::string, int>* test;

test = &std::map<std::string, int>();
(*test)["a"] = 0;
```

The error happens on last line from both.

Comment: `test = &std::vector<int>();` create a vector, gets it's address and then the vector immediately stops existing.

Comment: Don't try to make C++ behave like other languages.  It often doesn't work out well.  If you want a reference, just declare a reference.

Comment: Even if `*test` pointed to an actual empty vector, `(*test)[1]` would try to access an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: It does not stops existing, I can push_back() into it.

Comment: Trust us, it does stop existing.  What you are doing is called undefined behavior and one possible outcome is that it "works".

Comment: Most of the time when you try to shoot yourself in the foot you miss. Doesn't mean that shooting in the general direction of your foot is ok, because you miss most of the time. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @uIM7AI9S Your errors cause undefined behavior. It means anything can happen. Many (most?) errors in C++ do not require a crash or diagnostic, such code can appear to work for a bit. But the fact is your vector does not exist and `push_back` only appears to work. If you rely on this, inevitably you will eventually begin to see odd crashes and errors here or in other (seemingly unrelated) parts of your code. It's not possible to learn C++ by trial and error, and the absence of obvious signs of an error is not proof of correctness.

Comment: That won't even compile outside of VS (and for good reason)

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
test = &std::vector<int>();
```

This is not valid C++. You cannot take the address of a temporary.

Unfortunately, as an extension Visual Studio does permit you to do this; your resulting pointer is *immediately dangling* (because the temporary dies at the end of the line). Then, everything you try to do with the vector (which doesn't exist) has undefined behaviour.

*(Even if it were a valid pointer, you're trying to index elements that don't exist.)*

You can do what you want as long as you keep a proper, named object somewhere in scope. You can get a pointer to that object and get your reference semantics all over the place. However, this is dangerous because it will be difficult to ensure that the pointed-to object is alive when you need it to be. That's why smart pointers exist.

You're better off, in C++, sticking with value semantics. The language is best used when used as designed.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning a reference to a temporary vector to your pointer. The temporary dies imediately and your pointer dangles.

Also you try to access the second element of your vector which has `0` size.

You may try this, but we are not in the `new` `delete` era anymore.

```
std::vector<int>* test; 
test = new std::vector<int>(2); 
(*test)[1] = 0;

// done with test
delete test;
```

Answer (score 3):

> can't use array operator to array-based pointers

You can, if your pointer points to an object. Which yours don't.

> to use pointers, avoiding new keyword to obtain the same copying behaviour like in some other languages

you haven't really shown what behaviour you want, or said which languages you're trying to imitate, but in general: writing language A code in language B is a bad idea. The two will have different conventions, idioms and subtleties.

If you *do* insist on writing C++ that looks like another language, you need to figure out what specific behaviour you need, and how to implement that in C++ so it looks similar. This is often a lot of work, and writing C++ code that looks the way you want and happens to compile is not a sufficient solution.

As Lightness has pointed out your proximate error, I'm just going to mention that it is *trivial* to inspect your understanding of these things by writing a canary type, like

```
struct Canary {
    ~Canary() { cout << "Canary dtor\n"; }
    Canary() { cout << "Canary default ctor\n"; }
    Canary(Canary &&) { cout << "Canary move ctor\n"; }
    Canary(const Canary &) { cout << "Canary copy ctor\n"; }
    Canary& operator=(Canary &&) { cout << "Canary move assignment\n"; return *this; }
    Canary& operator=(const Canary &) { cout << "Canary copy assignment\n"; return *this; }
};

Canary *c = &Canary();
```

now you can easily step through your code in the debugger, or just run it and watch the output ...